# I want to work with android studio in my tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, tablet

I want to work with android studio in my tablet.
Do you know how to installs this program on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AIDE for using android studio and Eclips in android os

it works perfectly and also it has all android studio futures you can download it from this link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en